# ODP.NET not working

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

So I have Oracle 11 32bit installed on my PC. If I create a C# project and include the Oracle.DataAccess.dll I can connect just fine. If someone else makes a C# project and I open it, it fails on the Open method stating "TNS: Could not resolve the connection identifier specified. If I remove the reference from the other persons project and add it again from my PC, I get the same error.

We use LDAP here.
TNSPing works just fine on my PC.

Any ideas why I can make a program and reference the oracle dll and it works, but from someone elses program it doesn't? Is there any way I can trace what is going on externally of this app to the oracle drivers?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are encountering, but I know there are two different oracle data providers for .net.  The ones Microsoft originally provided are deprecated now, and you need ODP.Net from Oracle.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html

Comment: Yeah, I am using the Oracle provided ODP.NET. I wish MS would have kept making theirs as it was 100% easier to manage than these dang Oracle ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch but when you got the project from the other person, then was the "Copy Local" property of the Oracle dll set to true? If it was false, then it might be possible that the other person set the Oracle dll from his GAC and so the project found the oracle dll on his machine. However, when the project came to your machine, then the references file had the entry for Oracle dll but it was not able to find the "correct version" in your GAC or in the output path.

Comment: When I open the project from the other person and look at the reference the Oracle DLL is there. We are all picking from the Oracle directory.